# How to open folders with hotkeys in OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, hotkeys

I am trying to assign a hotkey to open a folder in snow leopard.  For example, in windows i could simply press the Windows+E to open the My Computer folder (or manually assign whatever folder i wanted to open).  Is there a way to get this same behavior in OSX?

I want to be able to launch applications, and open folder with my own keyboard mappings.

For launching applications I use automator, create a service that receives no input to 'launch application' (from the utilities library).  Then i can assign a keyboard shortcut to this service.  Now i can launch applications with keyboard shortcuts.

I still dont know how to open a folder.  I know this can be done using quicksilver - but am looking for an organic approach that does not require any additional installs.

Answer (score 2):

You can also instruct Automator to open a certain folder:

```
tell application "Finder" to open folder "Home:Documents"
```

Also note some Finder-specific keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> opens Applications
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> opens your Home folder
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> opens the Desktop
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> opens your Documents
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> opens the Computer (like Windows+E)

You can also press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter a folder's path to open it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Automator actions named "Get Specified Finder Items" and "Open Finder Items" in combination.

[image]